# New user registration for iOS app could be streamlined

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

The new user experience for a user that sees the SE app and downloads it from the App store could use some polish.

1. Does there need to be a captcha in the sign up page? (It makes landscape entry extremely cramped). The iOS app isn't likely scriptable and you could handle the text entry natively (although the password feedback is pretty awesome to explain how the proposed password is meeting the complexity requirements). [image: captcha for new user sign up]
2. When you sign up for a new user using SE as an option, it says to check your email for activation. If the user signs in before that is complete, this error message is given. Could it tell the user explicitly that the verification is still pending rather than the vague error message?

> **Error** Could not perform this request with your account. Please try logging back in. If this persists, let us know on meta.

A new user probably can't let anyone know anything on meta while their account is being created and not verified. At least provide a clickable URL if you are going to direct them to meta (MSE?) for assistance if the error can't be specific about the unregistered status of the account.

iOS alpha app (v1.0.0.67)